# TLS issue when sending to gmail through JavaMail

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

Turns out that JavaMail is a bit more frustrating than I thought it would be. I've looked at several examples online on how to send a simple SMTP email through Gmail's servers (but not through SSL). After trying several different examples of code, I keep concluding to the same example exception when I call `transport.connect()`. I keep getting this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l10sm302158wfk.21
     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
     at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:47)
```

Can someone please tell me what I should add or do to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.user", "blahblah@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.password", "blah");
    props.put("mail.port", "587");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.setSubject("This is a test");
    message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("blahblah2@gmail.com"));

    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable `STARTTLS`. Add one more property to your configuration:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the STARTTLS problem, but I now I'm getting this exception. Can you help me? Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                              
530 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 g2sm368231pbh.15... I checked the website that it included but I'm not finding any useful information.

Comment: Gah, yes, you'll also need to set the `mail.smtp.auth` property to `true`.

Comment: Thanks again! Nooooooow I'm getting this error... "failed to connect, no password specified?"... I know that I have provided the password as you can see from the code above. But is the password's properties tag named something else that I'm not providing correctly?

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should use an `Authenticator` rather than configuring the credentials. Remove both the `mail.user` and `mail.password` keys. Then instead of passing `null` as the second argument to `Session.getDefaultInstance`, create and pass an implementation of `Authenticator` that overrides the `getPasswordAuthentication` method - the details of this are easy.

Comment: Uhg, so this program works perfectly fine on my development desktop. But when I move it over to my server machine and run it, I'm getting this error: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: java.io.IOException: Exception in startTLS using socket factory class null: host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; Exception: java.security.ProviderException: Could not initialize NSS
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1880)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:648)... any ideas?

Comment: Did you change architecture when moving between the two environments? I think the NSS provider issue relates to the SSL configuration on the machine. If you're on Linux ensure that you have libnss3 and openssl installed.

Comment: The server is running on OpenSUSE, I think that OpenSSL is already installed. I'm going to try to figure out how to get libnss3 through the default repositories with YaST. Do you know if there are any other possibly important things I might need? Thanks for all your help on this by the way.

Comment: Never mind, I ended up finding the package I needed... all is good now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class CopyOfSendMail {

private static String SMPT_HOSTNAME = "my smtp port no";
private static String USERNAME = "root";
private static String PASSWORD = "root";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMPT_HOSTNAME);
    props.put("mail.from","aaa@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        }
    });
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom();
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                          "bbb@gmail.com");
        msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
        Transport.send(msg);
     } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Rob and Brian ! With help of u guys I'm putting the whole code here...  Any1 who is looking 4 creating simple mail sender can use the above code, it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here Mail Sender which is using MSN-SMTP service

My host is **smtp.live.com** and port is 587.

As given in [official doc of Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#hotmail), here you can get more info about best Java Mail mechanism to send and receive mails.

Properties of Mail Client are:

```
  Properties mailProps = new Properties();
  mailProps.put("mail.smtp.user",mailID);
  mailProps.put("mail.smtp.host",host);
  mailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  mailProps.put("mail.smtp.port",port);
  mailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(mailProps,null);
```

Sending mechanism is :

```
 SMTPTransport t=(SMTPTransport)mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
 System.out.println(" Taking protocol! ");
 t.connect(host, mailID, password);
 System.out.println(" Connection Successfull! ");
 t.sendMessage(mimMessage,mimMessage.getAllRecipients());
```

Note: 
Code is running well on local **Indian Server.** 
But this is not responding at **Azur Congo**:  Both are Linux server.

Error is:

```
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

Even if system property set manually:

```
 java -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true SendAMai
```

also @Rob Harrop  and @Brian 's points are ensured

```
if you're on Linux ensure that you have libnss3 and openssl installed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package enviando_email.enviando_email;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */

public class AppTest 
{

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testEmail() {
        
          final String username = "yourusername";
          final String password = "yourpass";
        
        try {
            
            Properties properties = new Properties(); 
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); /*autorizacao*/
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); /* autenticacação*/
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com"); /* servidor do gmail */
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); /* porta de saida do servidor */
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587"); /* especifica a porta a ser conectada pelo socket */
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); /* classe do socket de conexão SMTP */
            
            //cria sessão - recebe objeto autorizado para se manter na sessão 
            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
            
            Address[] toUser = InternetAddress.parse("recipient1@hotmail.com,recipient2@gmail.com");
            
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session); //pega sessão válida 
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username)); //pega o usuario que iniciou a sessão e envia mensagem por ele
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser); //para quem enviar email 
            message.setSubject("Chegou assunto do e-mail"); //Assunto do e-mail
            message.setText("Olá esse e-mail está sendo enviado pelo java mail");
            
            Transport.send(message);
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I put as follow above what works for me, i hope that helped you.