# Cannot send an email via jsp in gmail

Tags: java, jsp

I've the following code in a file called clave.jsp:

```
@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.detelexia.bbdd.Datos" %>
<%@ page import="com.detelexia.web.Utils" %>
<%@ page import = "java.text.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*, javax.mail.Service"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
 [....]
<div><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="email(); return false;" class="button button-alt">ENVIAR</a></div>
<script>
function email()  
{

Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",  "smtp.gmail.com");  
        props.put("mail.from","existingdirection@gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("existingdirection@gmail.com", "correctpassword");
        }
    });
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom();
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                          "existingdirection@gmail.com");
        msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
        Transport.send(msg);
     } catch (MessagingException mex) {

     }

}
</script>
[....]
```

The code is based in the second one shown here [TLS issue when sending to gmail through JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512430/tls-issue-when-sending-to-gmail-through-javamail), but although it's said to work I cannot get it to work. I've also tested to input root as user and password and to pass the user and password as shown there but it doesn't work.

But it doesn't seem to send something, maybe it's that the receiving inbox can't get the message but I doubt it.

Any idea of what I can be doing wrong? I've tried to check that code and a lot more of them but none of them seems to work and i don't know why, it all looks right.

Of course, the compilation of the page goes perfectly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello @user2638180 how can you use a server side jsp code inside a client side javascript function , may be you should start with basics

Answer (score 0):

Well, where do we start?

First of all you gotta understand the difference between a desktop application, where an action is fired by events such as click, double-click, keypress, etc. And a web application, where you need forms, requests, responses, if you take use on ajax, well, events + ajax (which leads you to know about request, responses, and forms).

I think you need to check the basics of web application development. Like the request/response life-cycle, forms, javascript, css, and html, for the presentation layer. Then you need to check the basics of Java (JSP, servlets, filters, classes, objects). And it would be good for you to learn about design patterns or at least how/when use/implement them depending on what you want to do (MVC, HMVC, DAO, DI/IoC, Observable Observer).

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Efra

Answer (score -1):

try the given below code to send email,  **but use this code into scriptlet <% code goes here %> not in JavaScript or any other client side script function**

I hope it will work.

```
String host="smtp.gmail.com";
final String user="it1006813052@gmail.com";//change accordingly
final String password="wooofqrzcjkjdmlaezr";//change accordingly

String to="it1006813052@gmail.com";//change accordingly

 //Get the session object

try { 
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.user",user); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); 
  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 

  props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");

  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); 

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
 return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
     }
   });

 //Compose the message
 try {
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("rohan@bhediya.com"));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
 message.setSubject("whass up?");
 message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");
 // add attatchment

 MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String file = "F:/emb3.png";
    String fileName = "emb3";
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);     


//send the message
 Transport.send(message);

   out.println("message sent successfully...");

     } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }
  catch(Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
```

you can remove attatchment part if you don't want to attatch anything

Comment: I think that is not a good practice, I mean, mix the server-side code with the presentation code. I know you can set some field or something like that, but something so specific like e-mail sending, is simply a bad idea to use it into a scriptlet, specially if your application goes bigger than expected.